# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I am use rnfirebase messaging

And I followed all the steps [this links](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/messaging/android)

But this error returns

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0.

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/installation/android#Update-Gradle

Comment: can you please share a bit more information, How is your app/build.gradle and project level build.gradle looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the information provided I can't really help but I did suffer from similar kind of issue while I was adding `react-native-firebase` to one of my projects.

Solution was in project level `build.gradle` file, move the `google()` statement in the `respositories` right to the top, end result looks like below one:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' 
    }
 // other things goes here...
}
```